# Best way to display a list sum as a web part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part, list-view, flow

I have a SharePoint list which is used to track money saved through individual projects in our team. I want a simple visual which displays the sum (total money saved) as a web part - what is the easiest/best way to do this?

I've looked a power automate/flows but am totally new to this. I thought there would be a way to display the sum (which is calculated in the list) but I'm coming up blank, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show the sum of single column in list view, you can use **Totals** in SharePoint list like:

[image]

**Reference**: [Total of a calculated column on Sharepoint 365 and MS Teams list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/89029/total-of-a-calculated-column-on-sharepoint-365-and.html)

Comment: I want the total or sum to show in a visual. I have the sums showing in the list but am unable to show that in a visual - I've played with power BI reports, but not all of our staff have the license to view it. The quick charts don't display the total only either.

Comment: You can do that using Power BI, but to share it with others they will need licenses. I think for your requirements, you can create a simple SPFx web part to show the sum in visual (as it is not possible with out of the box SharePoint capabilities).

Comment: Yeah, as above, I did a Power BI license but many of our staff don't have the license to view it. To recap: tried Power Bi; it wasn't suitable. Need a visual outside of the original list to display on the home page. Quick Charts are also not suitable. 

At the moment I have text web part that we have to manually update, but I was hoping for something automated